# Why does "LOAD DATA INFILE ..." fail with formatted date strings?

Tags: mysql

I am unable to get an export/import round-trip working for a single `DATETIME` formatted field. I must be able to load files with dates formatted as:

```
2/9/2022 0:00:00
```

Note the absence of leading '0' in the month, day, and hour field.

I'm attempting this simple round-trip in order to show myself that I understand the relevant date coercion behavior.

Here is a simple table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `load_test` (
  `some_field` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is an INSERT statement that adds a single row to this table:

```
INSERT INTO `load_test` (
    `some_field`)
VALUE (
    str_to_date('2/9/2022 0:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')
);
```

Here is a `SELECT INTO...` statement that dumps this into a CSV file:

```
(SELECT 'some_field')
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`some_field`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/store_test.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM `load_test`;
```

Here is what that file looks like:

```
"some_field"
"02/09/2022 00:00:00"
```

Here is my failing `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/store_test.csv' 
    INTO TABLE `load_test`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    SET
        `some_field` = STR_TO_DATE(@`some_field`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

When I execute this (in `MySQL Workbench`), I get the following complaint:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: 'some_field' for column 'some_field' at row 1
```

The documentation says that `LOAD DATE INFILE ...` is the counterpart to `SELECT INTO...`. I'm using the same date format string on both output and input, and I'm attempting to load the very same file that `SELECT INTO` stored earlier.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps some of the values in that column do not comply with the given format string. You should check your data first.

Comment: The data that I'm attempting to load is provided above (following the text that says "Here's what the data looks like"). It is literally the same data that `SELECT INTO...` stored. I have also confirmed that it loads without complaint when pasted into an `INSERT` statement. There is just one column ("some_field") and just one row. I don't see how it can not comply with the given format string.

Answer (score 1):

After much wailing, gnashing of teeth, trial, and many errors I found the answer -- there may be other ways, but this works.

The issue is that in the `SET` clauses, I was referencing a name ("@`some_field`") that was defined.

Here is a form that works:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/store_test.csv' 
    INTO TABLE `load_test`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (@`some_field`) SET
        `some_field` = STR_TO_DATE(@`some_field`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

This has several implications. It appears to me that the `SET` clause must include a phrase for each column to be set. That means the parenthesized list that precedes the `SET` must have an entry of the form "@`field_name`" for each field in the file to be imported. There must be corresponding phrase in the `SET` clause that references each temporary name.

When I only specified the columns that needed special processing the others were each null.

Here the actual working `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` command that I needed:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/import/files/foobar.csv'
    INTO TABLE `3p_day_rate_t`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (
        @`area`,
        @`fips`,
        @`us-counties-cases`,
        @`us-counties_1-cases`,
        @`us-counties_1_date`,
        @`us-counties-date`,
        @`predicted_date`,
        @`population2019`,
        @`case_growth_per_capita`,
        @`interim_cases_term`
    )
    SET
        `area` = @`area`,
        `fips` = @`fips`,
        `us-counties-cases` = @`us-counties-cases`,
        `us-counties_1-cases` = @`us-counties_1-cases`,
        `us-counties-date` = STR_TO_DATE(@`us-counties-date`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
        `us-counties_1_date` = STR_TO_DATE(@`us-counties_1_date`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
        `predicted_date` = STR_TO_DATE(@`predicted_date`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
        `population2019` = @`population2019`,
        `case_growth_per_capita` = @`case_growth_per_capita`,
        `interim_cases_term` = @`interim_cases_term`
```

While tedious, this at least works. It was hard enough for me to find this working answer that the exercise is perhaps valuable to those who come later with the same question.

Comment: *It appears to me that the SET clause must include a phrase for each column to be set.* ??? Who tells you about this? You may mix columns and user-defined variables as needed. ```LOAD DATA INFILE ... (column1, @column2, column3) SET column2=fn(@column2)```. In your query you may assign 7 columns directly and 3 - via UDV and expression.

Comment: @Akina: Understood. I meant that if only one column is mentioned in the `SET` clause, then only one column will be set in the resulting row. Nobody told me this -- I learned it by inspecting the table and finding null values for all but the columns mentioned in the SET clause.

Comment: *I meant that if only one column is mentioned in the SET clause, then only one column will be set in the resulting row.* Incorrect. Any column assigned in either columns list or SET clause will be set. Plus autoassigned columns (AUTO_INCREMENT, DEFAULT) and columns assigned in a trigger. But if columns list is skipped then all columns will be asssigned anycase.